# Redirect Laravel's Exception Handler

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys can anyone help me on how to make a *"customized exception handler"* and use it to redirect the user if there is an error but still have a link for the *"original exception handler"*. I don't know how to make a link for the exception handler because it is not shown on the `routes.php`.

For example:

```
<h1>This is an error page.</h1>
<a href="ExceptionHandler.php">What causes the error</a>
```

Any help or hints will do :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as exception handler url. You can customize exception handling by modifying `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` in your project. It inherits `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler` which has `renderHttpException` and `decorate` methods to render exceptions.

Comment: I ended up doing that. No link to view the errors for debug. So sad